# Unresolved compilation issue junit

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, compilation

I am not sure if this is a duplicate question, but could not find a satisfactory answer in any other threads.

I have a junit class and when I try to run my test cases, I am getting the following error.

> java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:    The import oracle
>   cannot be resolved    The import oracle cannot be resolved
>     OraclePreparedStatement cannot be resolved to a type
>     OraclePreparedStatement cannot be resolved to a type    OracleTypes
>   cannot be resolved to a variable
>
> at
>   com.csg.cs.riskit.db.GenericStatementCallback.(GenericStatementCallback.java:14)
>     at
>   com.csg.cs.riskit.db.SqlQueryBuilder$Executor.execute(SqlQueryBuilder.java:189)

It is happening for other classes also, which used to work previously.

I tried cleaning up the whole project, restarting my eclipse, removing and adding certain jars and all. But still the issue persists. Also, there are some compilation errors in other custom classes as well, which don't look like a real issue. It looks like an issue which happens when the project is not built properly. If that were the case, cleaning the project should work, but it does not in this case.

Can anyone please help me find a solution or redirect me to a thread which has an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience even the compilation errors that you do not think are a real issue, can in fact influence eclipses ability to build the project properly. It could be something not properly refactored, or a mistype of a word, that could be forcing the error. Also thoroughly check your imports as one of them may be the contain the error that is the source of your compilation error.

I have had similar issue with RFT (Eclipse integrated program for functional testing), and it wasnt until I resolved some of those compilation errors that the the project was able to be properly built and run smoothly again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The other compilation errors are like "variable (or a method) is undefined for type...". Those cannot be fixed as the specified variable or method exists in the specified class.